# Can Dynamic Multi-Dimensional arrays in C++ be initialized using nullptr

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to initialize a class variable which is a dynamic multidimensional array. My goal is not to fill the array with values during constructor phase. I would just like to initialize this variable such that it doesn't store garbage values.

a rough idea of my code:

```
Class a {

    Object **theArray;

    a() {
      theArray = nullptr
    }

}
```

The dynamic 2D array is meant to be allocated sometime later in execution. My question is, is this a valid operation and does it effectively make the 2D array point to nullptr instead of garbage values?

Comment: As long as you later initialize the array, this is the usual way to initailize a pointer if it can not be allocated right away.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a container class for managing the array. Then you cannot have bugs to do with memory management and your code is a whole lot simpler.